# Night Person in Fallout 4

Tags: fallout-4

So the`Night Person` perk gives me +2 perception during the night; this would mean I had a total of 8 perception. Would this unlock the `Sniper` perk?  Does it mean I could use that Sniper perk during the night and lose it during the day?

Comment: I'm almost positive that termporrary SPECIAL boosts do not unlock perk levels.  If I remember right, wearing glasses (+1 PER) did not allow me to access perks not available with my natural SPECIAL.

Comment: Nope, the `Night Person` perk does not allow you to get perks early, and neither does wearing SPECIAL enhancing gear, like glasses or Power Armor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it doesn't. In fact, the Perks screen only takes into consideration the base value of the stat, so between the times of 6pm and 6am with the Night Person perk your perception on the Perks screen will read its base value:

[image: perception skill tooltip]

It will only show its active value on the SPECIAL screen.

[image: SPECIAL screen]